# Parsing the metaData of a plugin in Qt5

Tags: qt, plugins, metadata

Qt doc says that QPluginLoader::metaData() allows us to read metadatas about a plugin, but there are no documentation about fields themselves, in order to parse the returned QJsonObject.
After qDebugging, here are the fields I receive :

```
IID
MetaData
className
debug
version
```

I understand MetaData is the stuff I put in myplugin.json, but can I rely on others fields (like IID) in a sustainable way or are they internal stuff that can change for the next Qt versions?

Comment: Normally if they are stated explicitly in the docs then: yes.  However in this case they have been documented in `QPluginLoader` "Notes provided by the Qt Community"...

Comment: As I said in my post, I deduced the "documentation" of those fields by myself but, if I base my application on the "IID" field, I need to know if this field is sustainable or if it could disappear one day.

Answer (score 0):

The metadata contains a key "MetaData" which has an QJsonObject as value. To get the meta data you could do something like this:

```
QPluginLoader plugin("path/to/plugin.dll");
QJsonValue pluginMetadata(plugin.metadata().value("MetaData"));
QJsonObject metaDataObject = pluginMetadata.toObject();

// If there is e.g. version string in the metadata with the key "version"
// return an empty string if there is no key->value pair
QString pluginVersion = metaDataObject.value("version").toString();
```

Comment: That wasn't my question.
My question is : "can I rely on other fields than MetaData itself, like IID, ...?"